# How to interprete this disassembled line by using dedexer?

Tags: android, dalvik, dex, jvm-bytecode, jasmin

The following is snipcode disassembled using [dedexer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dedexer/files/) on a android market app, in the `invoke-virtual`, I don't understand what can the original Java code be:

`invoke-virtual {v0},[Lcom/google/android/providers/AbstractGDataSyncAdapter$ClientDiffType;/clone  ; clone()Ljava/lang/Object;`

The `[` is supposed to be an array, then is it invoking the `clone` method on element in the array of type `com/google/android/providers/AbstractGDataSyncAdapter$ClientDiffType`?
Then why there is `;` between the class name and method name `clone`? A bug in the dedexer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names begin with an 'L' and end with a ';'. So `[Lcom/google/android/providers/AbstractGDataSyncAdapter$ClientDiffType;` is an array of `com.google.android.providers.AbstractGDataSyncAdapter.ClientDiffType`

I don't know what the '/clone ;' syntax is though. It does seem like it might be a bug in dedexer. The clone() right after that is obviously the method.

"then is it invoking the clone method on element in the array" - this is incorrect. It is invoking the clone method on the whole array, not on an element in the array.